# How to merge a branch and get conflict markers in GitHub for Windows or web

Tags: github, merge, github-for-windows

I am using GitHub on the web and with the Windows client, and I'm having trouble merging a branch into a master repo. I've created a pull request and get the message:

> We can't automatically merge this pull request.
>   Use the command line to resolve conflicts before continuing.

GitHub provides some command line examples, but they don't work for me (possible due to a proxy issue, which is another/off-topic issue). I'm wondering: **How can I get a merged file with *conflict markers* using either the web or the Windows client?**

This seems possible using the Mac client (see https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts/), and it seems to be possible if you are syncing in the same branch with the Windows client (see  [GITHUB Conflict Resolving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210706/github-conflict-resolving)), but I haven't figured out how to do it between a branch and the master.

Note: If this is completely impossible without using the command line, I'll accept an answer that explains how that might be done. The goal is to have a solution that is user-friendly enough so it can be passed on to my group and organization.

Answer (score 1):

Message from GitHub support:

> It's not currently possible to resolve merge conflicts via GitHub for Windows or using GitHub.com web interface, however I'll add your suggestion to our internal Feature Request List for consideration.